# Cómo realizar reemplazos en una string utilizando datos de una matriz en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista, matrices

```py
#example input M x N matriz
new_matrix_aux = [['X', 'B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'U1', 'L1', 'L2'], 
                  ['U1', 12,  3.0,  2.0, -1.0,  1.0,    0,    0], 
                  ['L1', 12,  2.0,  3.0,    0,    0,  1.0,    0], 
                  ['L2',  2, -2.0,  1.0,    0,    0,    0,  1.0]]

z_function = "Z = 1 * X1 + 4 * X2 + 0 * X3 + M * U1 + M * L1 + M * L2"
```

Aqui el codigo, aunque no da el resultado correcto ya que empieza realizando los reemplazos utilizando la fila de titulos de columnas y las de titulo de filas, recordar que la matriz puede tener cualquier cantidad de dimensiones pero siempre respeta que las 2 primeras columnas son de la variable y el coefiente independiente `B`

Y la primer fila siempre sera la de titulos de columnas.

```py
variables = new_matrix_aux[0][1:]  # Obtener las variables de la primera fila de la matriz
replacements = {var: 0 for var in variables}  # Inicializar los reemplazos con 0 para cada variable

# Realizar los reemplazos en la función Z
for col in range(1, len(new_matrix_aux[0])):
    column_name = new_matrix_aux[0][col]
    for row in range(1, len(new_matrix_aux)):
        variable = new_matrix_aux[row][0]
        value = new_matrix_aux[row][col]
        replacements[variable] = value

    z_function = z_function.replace(column_name, str(replacements[column_name]))

    print(f"Z_{column_name} = {z_function}")

    # Restaurar los reemplazos a 0 para la siguiente iteración
    for variable in replacements:
        replacements[variable] = 0
```

Todas las variables de la primer sublista que no aparescan al inicio de una de las siguientes sublistas deben ser reemplazadas en las `"Z = 1 * X1 + 4 * X2 + 0 * X3 + M * U1 + M * L1 + M * L2"` por `0`

El resto de variables deben ser reemplazadas por los valores de las columnas que indican las variables de la matriz `new_matrix_aux` asociadas a las variables que se indican en las filas de esta matriz

En la columna de `'X'` estan los nombres de las variables asociadas a los valores de las filas, la columna `'B'` esta el termino independiente de este sistema lineal aunque aqui no lo usaremos porque en el reemplazo en `Z` no ha terminos independientes, y el resto de columnas representan a las variables

Iterando las columnas de la matriz `new_matrix_aux`, y realizando los reemplazos en cada iteracion deberia ir imprimiendo lo siguiente en consola

```py
"Z_B  = 1 * 0 + 4 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 12 + M * 12 + M * 2"

"Z_X1 = 1 * 0 + 4 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 3.0 + M * 2.0 + M * -2.0"

"Z_X2 = 1 * 0 + 4 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 2.0 + M * 3.0 + M * 1.0"

"Z_X3 = 1 * 0 + 4 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * -1.0 + M * 0 + M * 0"

"Z_U1 = 1 * 0 + 4 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 1.0 + M * 0 + M * 0"

"Z_L1 = 1 * 0 + 4 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * 1.0 + M * 0"

"Z_L2 = 1 * 0 + 4 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * 0 + M * 1.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a como entendi el problema es que esta generando ecuaciones demas cuando solo deberia de generar tres. Siendo asi, una forma de resolverlo seria:

```
matrix_auxiliar = [
       ['X',  'B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'U1', 'L1', 'L2'],
       ['U1', 12,   3.,    2.,  -1.,   1.,    0,  0],
       ['L1', 12,   2.,    3.,    0,    0,   1.,  0],
       ['L2', 2,   -2.,    1.,   0.,    0,    0,  1.]
       ]

z_f = "Z = 1 * X1 + 4 * X2 + 0 * X3 + M * U1 + M * L1 + M * L2"

aux_dct = {x[0]:x[1:] for x in zip(*matrix_auxiliar)}


zf_dct = {f'Z_{x}': None for x in aux_dct['X'] }

for i in range(3):
    zf_nm = f'Z_{aux_dct["X"][i]}'
    zf_aux = z_f[:]
    for j in [x for x in aux_dct if x != 'X']:
        zf_aux = zf_aux.replace(j,str(aux_dct[j][i]))
    zf_aux = zf_aux.replace('Z', zf_nm)
    zf_dct[zf_nm] = zf_aux
```

Donde el resultado seria el siguiente diccionario (Se puede cambiar a lista en caso de requerirlo):

```
zf_dct = {
'Z_L1': 'Z_L1 = 1 * 2.0 + 4 * 3.0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * 1.0 + M * 0'
'Z_L2': 'Z_L2 = 1 * -2.0 + 4 * 1.0 + 0 * 0.0 + M * 0 + M * 0 + M * 1.0'
'Z_U1': 'Z_U1 = 1 * 3.0 + 4 * 2.0 + 0 * -1.0 + M * 1.0 + M * 0 + M * 0'
}
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Aclaro que es mejor usar el formateo de cadenas (dentro de lo posible) que reemplazar constantemente una subcadena (además, esto es propenso a errores (prueba reemplazar "x2" por "x" y luego "x" por "1"))

Comment: Concuerdo contigo @Dante S. Aunque en este caso, la forma en que estaba planteada la pregunta, no parecia indicar que se podia modificar la cadena de texto original por formateo de cadenas. En cualquier caso, concuerdo que este ultimo caso es significativamente mas eficiente.